# How do I specify encryption type when using s3remote for DVC

Tags: dvc

I have just started to explore DVC. I am trying with s3 as my DVC remote. I am getting

But when I run the `dvc push` command, I get the generic error saying

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

which I know for a fact that I get that error when I don't specify the encryption.

It is similar to running `aws s3 cp` with `--sse` flag or specifying `ServerSideEncryption` when using boto3 library. How can I specify the encryption type when using DVC. Coz underneath DVC uses boto3 so there must be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer for this immediately in the DVC discord channel!! By default, no encryption is used. We should specify what server-side encryption algorithm should be used.

Running dvc remote modify worked for me!

```
dvc remote modify my-s3-remote sse AES256
```

There are a bunch of things that we can configure here. All this does is that it adds an entry of `sse = AES256` under the `['remote "my-s3-remote"']` inside the `.dvc/config` file.

More on this here
https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/modify